# Unable to join server to specific active directory site

Tags: active-directory, domain

Two sites are in my AD:

```
Site1 - subnets connected to it are 1.1.2.0,1.1.3.0,1.1.4.0.
Site2 - subnets: 1.2.1.0/24.
```

I have two DCs up and running on both sites. Can I join a server whose subnet is `1.1.2.0` (belongs to Site1) to the domain through The DCs in Site2?

Answer (score 0):

Does each site have their own DCs?

If not then the DCs in site2 will register their SRV records against Site1 as well as site2. So the quick answer is yes. Servers / PCs in site1 can be joined to the domain by DCs in site2 as long as the are using the correct DNS servers that can resolve the correct SRV records.

Hope this helps,

Mike.

P.S are those IP Address only for illustrative purposes?

Comment: Yes, each site has two DCs. Plus, you're correct about the IPs.

Comment: DNS records for the DCs in site1 are present in \domain_name\_sites\site1 in the DNS forward lookupzone, and vice versa regarding site2, so that does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Is the problem that Servers are not joining the domain? what exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, the servers don't join the domain. The errors is: "Active Directory Domain Controller for the domain cfould be not be conacted. The following error occured when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resuorce record used to locate AD DC for domain."

Comment: And do you get an error message?

Comment: What DNS entries are you using in the Server you are trying to join? Do the servers you are trying to join have network connectivity to the DCs?